# MS SQL Server Connection with Node JS

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am a newbie to any kind of back-end and as my university project I have to link my SQL Server to a front-end. I'm having trouble linking it to Node JS. Here's a piece of code that I wrote. It always logs "Failed" to the console.

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'mypasshere',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'TestDatabase'
};

sql.connect(config, (err) => {
    if (err) console.log('Failed to connect to SQL Server.', err);
    else {
        console.log('Connected to SQL Server.');

        const request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('SELECT * FROM dbo.Users', (err, result) => {
            if (err) console.log('Failed to execute SQL query.');
            else console.log(result);
        });
    }
});
```

```
Failed to connect to SQL Server. ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - self-signed certificate
    at /Users/airejtashfeen/Desktop/Nodejs Project/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/connection-pool.js:85:17
    at Connection.onConnect (/Users/airejtashfeen/Desktop/Nodejs Project/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:838:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Connection.emit (/Users/airejtashfeen/Desktop/Nodejs Project/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:959:18)
    at Connection.socketError (/Users/airejtashfeen/Desktop/Nodejs Project/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1340:12)
    at /Users/airejtashfeen/Desktop/Nodejs Project/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:2242:25
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - self-signed certificate
      at Connection.socketError (/Users/airejtashfeen/Desktop/Nodejs Project/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1340:28)
      at /Users/airejtashfeen/Desktop/Nodejs Project/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:2242:25
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    code: 'ESOCKET'
  }
}
```

I'm using SQL via docker along with Azure Data Studio since I'm on a Mac.

Comment: You're never new enough not to log the real error message and add it to your question. Otherwise it's hard to help you. I'm guessing your docker doesn't have 1433 port open but who knows

Comment: Apologies, this was my first ever question. I have included the error message now, please check it out.

Comment: Have you read the [Microsoft SQL Server client for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) documentation yet? Did you try looking for the phrase "self-signed" on it?

Comment: That's much better. " self-signed certificate" - meaning you should probably send a trust certification option with your mssql connection string, like `options: {
        encrypt: true,
        trustServerCertificate: true
    }` Read more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987786/verify-certificate-from-sql-server-in-node

Comment: That fixed it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I was just assuming it might be the first line that is causing this error. You have misspelled the mysql part.

const sql = require('mssql');

const sql = require('mysql');

You can try it and let me know if it works fine.

Comment: Hello, no I was using Microsoft SQL. I have resolved the issue by sending a trust certification option.